# Decorador Django

Tags: django

Buenas tardes estoy implementado el decorador @login_required en mi aplicación (a la cual solo se puede acceder si estan autenticados)

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/usuarios/login")
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
```

Con las otras vistas obtengo lo que necesito, pero con el index sucede un error 404.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solicito su colaboración para corregir este problema

Comment: Hola!, para que los demás usuarios puedan ayudarte, me parece que seria mejor que colocaras el código completo del archivo index, así podríamos revisar bien que problema ocurre.

Comment: Dice que no hay ruta y seguramente tampoco una vista para manejar el login... consulta la documentación https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator ahí viene un ejemplo. Inténtalo y si sigues teniendo problemas, edita tu pregunta...

Comment: @toledano la vista si existe y como mencione anteriomente el problema solo es con el index ya que con la otras vistas funciona bien

Comment: @Victor-Random Asi esta el codigo del index ya que no hace nada mas que presentar una plantilla html

Comment: te recomendaría que en tu decorador de `login_required` añadas un `/` para que haga bien la redirección, ya que al tener el `$` tu url (en el archivo de tu urls.py, en la linea donde pones la expresion regular), entonces hace el match con una url terminada en `/` y no en `?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a @German Alzate por su colaboración me funciono quedando de la siguiente forma los archivos:

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/usuarios/login/")
def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
```